# Tor Browser not able to open sites

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, censorship

I am not able to open any sites with tor browser from my win 10 laptop in office, even though I could do this earlier. I suspect my IT admin is now blocking tor through the office router/firewall. Even though browser starts fine and shows the tor circuit, sites do not load. I can see the browser trying to open site and then below error appears. It is also surprising that it is the same situation, even when I connect the laptop to the internet through my phone and office LAN is disconnected !! Can my laptop be configured to compulsory access company router through net (block tor) ?

> Secure Connection Failed
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Comment: Do you use Kaspersky AV?

Comment: This is because the IT department is trying to MITM your connection (so they can view everything you are doing) with their own certificate. Do NOT attempt to bypass this warning without understanding the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a similar problem was caused by Kaspersky Internet Suite. I uninstalled it and now Tor works fine again.